# Could a Halfling Warlock Ride a Pseudodragon?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, familiars, mount

What I would like to know is, can I ride a pseudodragon or get carried ( by its feetclaws) by an Imp. Without taking any attack penalties. Not really looking for cover bonuses.

I have a Halfling Warlock Height: 2' 11" Weight: 38 lb. With light armor (5lb) and arcane focus crystal (1lb) making a combined weight of 44lb.

A Imp and pseudodragon strength is 6. 6 strength on a tiny creatures carry weight is X3/4 so 0.75 X 60lb (41-60 lb is considered a heavy load) = 45lb

Which gives me a huge 1lb wriggle room on being carried.

So could it work? I don't think my DM uses the encumbered rules (It hasn't come up anyway.) I want to know if it's viable before making my pitch.

Side note: To do this I've considered what happens to all my weapons and equipment. I thought about having my other weapons and equipment in a satchel that is dropped if I try and ride my familiar. To use something inside the satchel I have to spend my movement to reach the bag and spend an action taking something out of the bag and readying it. 
This means for the bonus of flying and being out of melee range, I do not have access to anything other then my arcane focus. (For example no potions on hand.)

Comment: Please, D&D gods, let the answer be 'yes.'

Comment: light armor (5lb) and arcane focus crystal (1lb) - is it everything you possess? No loot, rations, artifacts, pebbles? Than what's the point in adventuring?

Comment: Tried to cover what happens with all my other items in the side note.  Everything is contained in a bag/satchel that gets dumped on the ground when I want to get carried.  So for the Pro of being carried,  I have the Con of having no items on me and to use. If i needed a potion or something I'd have to move back to the bag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No** you cannot ride PHB p. 198.

> A willing creature that is at least one size larger than
>   you and that has an appropriate anatomy can serve as a
>   mount, using the following rules.

A Halfling is Small and both of these creatures are Tiny which is one size category *smaller* not larger. Note: you *can* ride on any of your Medium sized companions:

[image: Master Blaster Mad Max: Beyond Thunderdome]

**Yes** you can be carried.

Comment: Assuming the familiar has the ability to grasp me, would being carried effect attack rolls?

Comment: @NisFoTra: I think that is in the realm of DM rulings. Just picturing the scene (a smaller animal flying and carrying a larger one, perhaps by grabbing its shoulders, looks clumsy to me), if I were DM, I would probably impose disadvantage whilst being carried like that, and probably advantage to ranged attackers. But your mileage may vary . . .