# If a person is wearing a Cloaker and they cast invisibility does the Cloaker go invisible too?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, invisibility

So I made the mistake once of allowing *Invisibility* to work on two creatures when one of them is carrying the other. One of my players is insistent that a creature climbing onto another creature counts as being carried, in spite of me deciding to never let that happen again.

He then asked the following question as a basis for his argument:

> If a person is wearing a Cloaker as a cloak and they become Invisible per the *Invisibility* spell, does the Cloaker not become invisible too?

Seeing how that is actually a more legitimate example of one creature *actually* being "worn or carried" I am not sure how that works. *I am willing to ignore how it was ruled before, as I am partly asking for future campaigns where there is not a history of the players doing it.*

Comment: How exactly is the person ‘wearing’ a Cloaker as a cloak? (That's like using a tiger as a couch—the first question anyone has about the situation isn't “how does invisibility work here?”, it will be “*run away you're about to be eaten*”.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm not 100% sure how they're doing it, really. Hopefully that situation never comes up, but the more important thing is that it's actually a creature that you might find on another creature in such a fashion. Perhaps the player is a _very_ persuasive Arcane Trickster, it's been Dominated by someone, or some other narrative stuff. If nothing else, it at least has the False Appearance of a mundane cloak.

Comment: [Flatbears... they'll mess you up.](https://gyazo.com/91fd6ebddd1b06035a991bfb4abd87c9)

Comment: There's a doppelganger in Undermountain who wears a cloaker. The answer to how you wear a cloaker? With the cloaker's consent. Apparently the doppelgangers negotiated an accord with the cloakers nearby.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### RAW, Cloaker is not Invisible.

A creature is not an item you carry:

> **Anything** the target is wearing or carrying is invisible as long as it is on the target’s person.

That is any objects, or things, not other creatures. Crawford confirms:

> Nope, that invisibility works on the fiend and its gear.

http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/03/24/invisible-master-warlock/

### It's DM's Call

The DM can retcon previous stuff, allow the cloaker to be an exception, or allow *anything carried* to include creatures.

### See Also

[Imp familiars Invisibility affecting a PC](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/82973/imp-familiars-invisibility-affecting-a-pc)

Comment: The _Sage Advice_ seems to refer to someone asking if ah Imp can even target another creature with its Invisibility Action, which it can't really do. And now I am considering the possibility that I have posted a Duplicate of the linked question...

Comment: The intent of the question is there was an idea floating around of using an imp to carry a halfling and have the halfling turn invisible with the imp.  The imp's invisibility reads just like the spell in regards to "anything it is carrying"

Comment: Anything includes creatures. See #8 [definition of thing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thing) (e.g. "not a living thing is sight"). Thing includes [individual](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/individual). Thus, *anything* includes creatures.

Comment: While I would agree with you in modern useagel however, the rules as intended, as stated by Crawford, is that things in this instance are objects, not creatures.

Answer (score 2):

> A creature you touch becomes invisible until the spell ends. Anything the target is wearing or carrying is invisible as long as it is on the target’s person. The spell ends for a target that attacks or casts a spell.
>   (Player's Basic Rules Version 0.3, Page 94)

According to the rules, the Cloaker would not become invisible, as the Cloaker is not a thing. It is a creature.

Comment: Is that to maintain consistency with ruling in a similar way before?

Comment: @Javelin Yes. If they hadn't already allowed carried creatures to be invisible, I would say they shouldn't make the Cloaker invisible.

Comment: I'm willing to ignore that sort of precedence, actually. If you want to change your answer to reflect that, I think you should.

Comment: OK, but please *change* the answer, don't just add a bit to the end that contradicts the beginning. [Write your answer as if it is the first and final version, without edit notes or old, obsolete parts.](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/dont-signal-your-edits-in-text)

Comment: See #8 [definition of thing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thing) (e.g. "not a living thing is sight"). Thing includes [individual](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/individual). Thus, *anything* includes creatures.

Comment: Also #3 at the same link, "an inanimate object distinguished from a living being". But while I would be willing to allow invisibility based on definitions, as @J. A. Streich pointed out, Crawford stated it was for objects, not creatures.

Comment: @Makyen, in D&D objects are often referenced as *Things* opposed to *Creatures* for individuals and monsters. You do not always follow the dictionary definition to the letter...

Answer (score -2):

I would rule that the player had something on them that allowed the spell to apply to both & that the spell states that it affects "A creature" which precludes it applying to more without a modifier.

Comment: Can you clarify the first part of your answer?

Comment: I think the first part is suggesting a retcon of the previous time it worked, saying that “something” let it happen before and that “something” isn't in effect now, so it doesn't work now.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a read through the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you have the time.