# Would the spell Disintegrate affect a carried creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

During a recent D&D 5e session, a Retriever picked up a player character and started to move, using this ability:

> If the paralyzed creature is Medium or smaller, the retriever can pick it up as part of the retriever’s move and walk or climb with it at full speed. (*Mordenkainen’s Tome of Foes*)

Another player character then cast Disintegrate on the Retriever. The text of disintegrate includes:

> A creature targeted by this spell must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, the target takes 10d6 + 40 force damage. The target is disintegrated if this damage leaves it with 0 hit points. **A disintegrated creature and everything it is wearing and carrying, except magic items, are reduced to a pile of fine gray dust**. (*Basic Rules, pg. 233*)

If the Retriever was successfully disintegrated, would the character being carried also be disintegrated?

Comment: A similar situation: "[Does a Familiar I’m carrying turn invisible with me if I cast Greater Invisibility on myself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/145064)"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## RAW the second creature is disintegrated

I cannot see how *picking someone up and moving around* is not carrying. And *disintegrate* is very clear it disintegrates

> and everything it is wearing and carrying

which the includes the unfortunate PC, but not their magic items because

> except magic items

Now, 5e  usually makes a clear distinction between creatures and objects, but *disintegrate* does not specify "all nonmagical objects" but "everything ... except magical items" which would include a carried creature.

#### However...

...this does look like an oversight (*i.e.* the possibility of carried creatures was probably not considered). Disintegrate says:

> On a failed save, the target takes 10d6 + 40 force damage. The target is disintegrated if this damage leaves it with 0 hit points.

This seems to indicate, that the idea of *disintegrate* is not to ignore hit points which it would do if the carried creature was simply disintegrated.

#### Therefore...

...it seems very reasonable to rule otherwise. The ruling should take a form that allows the carried creature to be protected by their hit points.

This could be done by also dealing damage to the carried creature (partially or complete; with or without save). Discussing balance implications of these options is beyond the scope of this answer, however.

One very simple solution would be ruling that there is a frontier between both creatures and only the targeted creature is affected. This would make it so that *disintegrate* works as it would if the incapacitated character was close by but not being carried

Answer (score -4):

## Disintegrate destroys carried objects, but people aren't objects

Disintegrate destroys "everything" that is being worn or carried (except magic items).

[Everything](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20everything) means: "all things". A ["thing"](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20thing) is "an object that one need not, cannot, or does not wish to give a specific name to." or "an inanimate material object as distinct from a living sentient being."

Creatures do not fit this definition, what's more, in 5e there is a clear distinction between creatures and objects - creatures are not considered to be a kind of object and the terms are not used interchangeably.

While the creature is being carried, they are not a "thing" and so aren't part of "everything". It is clear that the "things" being referred to are swords, armor, shields, items, etc.

Comment: +1, a similar situation occurs with casting *invisibility* on mounts or creatures carrying other creatures where the spell is clearly meant to affect only one creature. Plus this avoids the strange result of *disintegrate* no longer being an option for Twinned Spell

Comment: Well, the answer doesn't really cover that, either. But I'll delete comments as they aren't relevant to this answer. But I disagree with your connection between the two. Mounts are different and treat riders differently than something carried.