# Can a Pact of the Chain Imp familiar confer invisibility and flight onto its Warlock?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, warlock, familiars, invisibility

An imp has an innate fly speed of 40 and a carrying capacity of 45lbs (15 X 6 STR / 2) . And, it can turn invisible at will, conferring that to any equipment it is wearing or carrying:

> The imp magically turns Invisible **until it attacks, or until its Concentration ends** (as if concentrating on a spell). **Any Equipment the imp wears or carries is Invisible with it.**

There are 3 immediately relevant considerations:

1. Magic items

- a.**Bag of holding** - Does not weigh more than 15 lbs.

> The bag can hold up to 500 pounds, not exceeding a volume of 64 cubic feet. **The bag weighs 15 pounds, regardless of its contents**.

A PC can enter the bag, the imp can carry it to confer invisibility. The bag does run out of oxygen in 10 minutes:

> Breathing creatures inside the bag can survive up to a number of minutes equal to 10 divided by the number of creatures (minimum 1 minute), after which time they begin to suffocate.

<del>But, there is nothing to stop the player from keeping his head and neck outside of the bag.</del>
[The bag's oxygen will deplete in that time](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114708/can-you-still-suffocate-in-an-open-bag-of-holding?noredirect=1&lq=1), but 10 minutes of flight and invisibility is more than enough to infiltrate/ escape a dire situation/ achieve a strategic position. Especially if you retreat back into the bag ("lather; rinse; repeat") when enemies get close.

- b. **[Sack of Carrying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/201308/does-this-sack-of-carrying-work-as-simpler-replacement-for-bag-of-holding)**

> This item appears like a normal, large sack that **weighs 5 pounds. It can hold 12 cubic feet or 360 pounds, without changing its total
> weight.** Creatures in the sack can breathe normally. You can put
> objects or creatures into the sack or take them out with a normal
> object interaction.

2. **Enlarge/Reduce** - *Reduce* reduces a creatures weight by a factor of 8.

> The target's size is halved in all dimensions, and its weight is reduced to **one-eighth of normal**.

For many humanoids (<= 360lbs), this is well within an imp's carrying capacity. So, for a second level spell, a PC gets a full minute of flight AND invisibility.

Moreover, RAW this invisibility does not end if the PC attacks or casts a spell, because the imp is the one concentrating on the invisibility, not the PC. So, theoretically, from 120 ft in the air, totally invisible, the PC can *Eldrich Blast* to his or her heart's content.

There is a nuance (mentioned here: [Imp familiars Invisibility affecting a PC](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/82973/imp-familiars-invisibility-affecting-a-pc?rq=1)) that a PC is not strictly "Equipment", and therefore does not receive invisibility. But, this is trivial to work around. For example,

> A basket can hold **2 cubic feet/40 pounds of gear**.

A **Reduced** medium PC could sit (perhaps awkwardly) in the basket, surrounded by a cloak and receive the same benefits of being inside a *Sack* or *Bag of Holding*.

3. **Any creature weighing < 40lbs.** - *ibid.*

---

### Is it RAW legal? Isn't this grossly overpowered?

---

Note on carrying capacity:

[Lifting and Carrying](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Using%20Each%20Ability#h-Lifting%20and%20Carrying)

> Your carrying Capacity is your Strength score multiplied by 15. (...) For a Tiny creature, halve these weights.

Comment: You don't need to use Enlarge/Reduce to put someone into a Bag of Holding. The bag can carry up to 500 lbs and 64 cubic feet of material. A typical player character, even with equipment, will weigh less then 500 lbs, and a human body occupies less than 30 cubic feet. You can put someone in unreduced.

Comment: You seem to be asking a lot of technical, theoretical questions. Have you played a game yet? This kind of thing, no matter how legal, isn't usually the right thing at most tables. I am guessing you are new and keen, but just play some games before you start to worry about this kind of thing or get swept away with cool options.

Comment: I have been playing my first ever game/campaign for about a year now, if that matters. I am interested in the technical/theoretical aspects of the game system, hence the nature of the questions. I believe that asking  these questions is a valuable way to refine the game.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin Does the opening expand for larger-sized things?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### RAW, a PC can gain *some* of these benefits.

The apparent consensus for the respective scenarios:

1. Inside a magic item.

- **a.** An imp **CAN** carry a PC inside a *Bag of Holding*, which provides many of the practical benefits of both flight and invisibility. But, the PC is probably limited by being within the extradimensional space of the bag.
- **b.** An imp **CAN** carry a PC inside a *Sack of Carrying*, which provides many of the practical benefits of flight, and the question of invisibility is left up to the DM.

2. An imp **CAN** carry a PC, weighing less than 45lbs. So, a 2nd level *Reduce* spell can effectively grant a medium creature (weighing 360lbs = 45lbs * 8 ***Reduced** weight*) 1 minute of flight by which to avoid traps or obstacles. But, this does **NOT** necessarily confer invisibility to the PC.

Reduce:

> Duration: Concentration, Up to 1 minute (...)
> The target's size is halved in all dimensions, and its **weight is
> reduced to one-eighth of normal**.

3. *Ibid*

---

Imp's carrying capacity with 6 STR = 45lbs:

> Your carrying Capacity is your Strength score multiplied by 15. (...)
> For a Tiny creature, halve these weights.

Comment: @GroodyTheHobgoblin, does that seem correct to you?

Comment: To give some feedback on my downvote, you haven’t supported this answer. You provide a couple of rulings and no explanation of how the rules back up those rulings.

Comment: I see. Let me try to add some citations.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov, is that what you meant?

Comment: @nonymous Yes, I'd say this sounds correct.

Comment: c.f.
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/82821/could-a-halfling-warlock-ride-a-pseudodragon
- https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/82973/imp-familiars-invisibility-affecting-a-pc

Answer (score 12):

### This is unlikely to work

The primary problem with this plan is not that a carried creature is not affected by invisibility<sup>1</sup>. The problem is rather that the premise "*there is nothing to stop the player from keeping his head and neck outside of the bag*" is not correct.

[Bag of Holding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4581-bag-of-holding) says:

> Retrieving an item from the bag requires an action.

As further supported by this question about [breathing from an open bag of holding](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114708/can-you-still-suffocate-in-an-open-bag-of-holding), the opening of the bag is not a normal opening. You cannot shake out its contents with an object interaction, for example: retrieving an item from the bag explicitly requires an action.

This means if you are in the bag, you cannot just stick your head out. You need someone outside the bag to *retrieve you* with an action, and you also cannot be half-way in or out the bag. You either are in the bag, or you are retrieved and outside the bag after being retrieved.

---

<sup>1</sup> In this case, the wording for an [imp's invisibility](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16933-imp) extends only to *equipment*, while the question you link and the [invisibility spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/invisibility) uses a wording of "anything worn or carried", so I think invisibility would not apply here, either.

One can argue that a [carried creature should count as equipment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/200459/does-a-carried-creature-get-brought-along-when-teleporting-using-the-echo-knig/200465#200465), but the voting consensus on this points to "no".

Putting the PC into a sack or basket will not reduce their weight, so the imp will not be able to carry them. Using *reduce* to shrink them in this case *might* work around that (don't forget the weight of their equipment), but they still would not be invisible: probably not to begin with, and for sure not anymore once they came out of cover to have line of effect for their casting spells.

Putting them into a *bag of holding* makes the invisibility question a moot point, because in that case, the only thing the imp carries and makes invisible is the bag; the PC is not even there to be made invisible, they are then in an extradimensional space.

Comment: Ok, the *Bag of Holding* hack might not work for the reasons you say. But, those same reasons mean the *Basket* hack *does* work. Importantly, the **Reduce** spell reduces their weight, not "putting them in the basket".

Comment: @nonymous a basket+cloak that has been made invisible doesn't become an "invisibility cloak". Imo the reduced PC - who doesn't count as equipment and is not turned invisible - should simply become visible to everyone, floating in the air, once the items covering him go invisible.

Comment: @TheGamer007, while that does somewhat reconcile the RAW with the desired game balance, it does seem a bit illogical. Magic, of course isn't logical. But, if we follow your suggestion we get to the point where we have to say that the PC appears totally naked, floating in the air.

Comment: @nonymous: there's an important difference there: the imp's invisibility says "any equipment" where greater invisibility in the linked question says "anything". It's trivial to rule that a familiar (or, indeed, a PC) is not equipment but is a thing, thus an imp (using their own invisibility) carrying a basket with a reduced PC results in a visible PC hovering in the air while a familiar in the pocket of a PC who's invisible due to greater invisibility would also be invisible.

Comment: @minnmass. I did recognize that after I posted, and removed the citation before you added this comment. Thank you.

Comment: So, the conclusion should be, *Reduce* gives you naked flight for 1 minute, and the *Bag of Holding* gives you invisible flight for 10 minutes, but you can't target creatures outside of the bag (unless the DM rules that extradimensional space doesn't violate the range limitations of your action)?

Comment: @nonymous: If it was me, I would probably say the equipment on the character is still the character's and not the imp's and therefore not invisible, so you might see the character (in his equipment) floating around. May I refer you to Thomas' eloquent discussion that [If a feature requires you to get naked, you've probably misunderstood the feature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/194962/do-other-sources-of-invisibility-make-worn-or-carried-items-invisible/194963#194963) for an entertaining exploration of nakedness in D&D?

Comment: These rulings seem extremely questionable to me. The core assumption is that a PC is an "item". I think we all know that is not a well founded assumption, right? There is way too much gratuitous literalism for you to have that assumption. It's jarring to say that you can't leave the flap of a bag of holding open or shake items out, but then handwave "PCs are items". The dissonance is too much for me to vibe this answer!

Comment: @user77842 Thanks for the feedback. Item is defined as "an individual article or unit, especially one that is part of a list, collection, or set", like in this case the collection of things that are in the bag. Like "thing", it is generally used to cover anything, creatures as well as objects, as these are really the most practical ways to refer to something that is not limited to be an "object", which already has a specific in-game defintion. But you are right, this may be worth a separate question.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin  I'm fairly sceptical about the idea of referring to a person as an "item". Maybe it's different in your dialect, but in mine that just doesn't work. 2 people can be an item, but not one.

Comment: @user77842 I made [a question for it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/201239/does-the-term-item-also-apply-to-creatures), so this can be resolved. Are you from India? When I lived there couples were referred to as "an item", I recall that.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin And that’s very obviously not what “item” means in the rules ever.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin No, I'm not, also not following the logic, is it a stereotype that Indian people do not refer to people as "items"? And yeah, a couple is called "an item" here too. Does this mean the rules change when attempting to pull 2 PCs who are dating out of the bag? I seriously doubt it.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if any rules would be affected if two PCs did count as an "item".